# T-SQL How to escape star (*) character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, escaping, character

I want to search about this string

```
*|*
```

or more specific

```
LIKE '%*|*%'
```

but the

```
*
```

means the symbol itself. How to escape it?

EDIT: Actually, I was mislead because of other [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978005/why-conversion-numeric-to-varchar-does-not-give-overflow-message)  in my code. Anyway, you are completely right that in LIKE statement there is no special meaning for the * character.

Comment: Somewhere in my store procedures this string is add in a table. That's why I am searching about it. I try this \* but nothing was return.

Comment: * is not a wildcard (barring translation layers); `if 'aa *|* bb' like '%*|*%' select 'y'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to escape it. `*` has no special value in a `like` clause

```
 select * from yourtable where field LIKE '%*|*%'
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859(v=sql.100).aspx